# Fabric.js - Unable to set properties dynamically

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to set the `direction` dynamically but something is not working. I do not get an error.

```
function moveSelection(keyPressed) {
    var group = canvas.getActiveGroup(),
    obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

    if(!group && !obj) {return;}

    var direction = '',
        sign = '',
        operators = {
            '+': function(a, b) { return a + b },
            '-': function(a, b) { return a - b },
        };
    switch(keyPressed) {
        case 37:
            direction = 'left';
            sign = '-';
        break;
        case 38:
            direction = 'top';
            sign = '-';
        break;
        case 39:
            direction = 'right';
            sign = '+';
        break;
        case 40:
            direction = 'bottom';
            sign = '+';
        break;
    }

    if(group){
        group.set({
            direction : operators[sign](group.get(direction), 1)
        });
        canvas.renderAll();
    } else {
      obj.set({
        direction : operators[sign]( obj.get(direction),1 )
      });
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
```

But when i change the code to the following then it works fine.. What is wrong? Thank you:

```
obj.set({
    'left' : operators[sign]( obj.get(direction),1 )
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### TLDR

Use `obj.set(direction, ...)`.

### But why?

I've been bitten by this few times myself. Even after knowing that it's not supposed to work :)

**But this is how Javascript works**:

In your snippet, the "direction" in object literal is interpreted as "direction" property:

```
obj.set({
  direction : operators[sign]( obj.get(direction),1 )
});
```

just like `foo` in this object literal:

```
var foo = 'x';
var obj = { foo: 'bar' };
```

creates a property named "foo" rather than property named "x" (which `foo` *variable* "contains").

It might seem a little weird, since you're not writing:

```
var obj = { 'foo': 'bar' };
```

where foo is written as a **string literal** rather than an **identifier**. But to Javascript (up to ECMAScript 5), it doesn't really matter. The only difference is that using identifier notation, you can only represent properties that are also valid... identifiers.

So these, for example, are invalid as identifiers:

```
{
  'foo-bar': 'baz',
  '5leafs': 123,
  'or.with': 'dots'
}
```

which is why we have to write them as string literals.

This confusion might also come from the fact that **bracket notation** in Javascript *does* allow to create dynamic properties:

```
var foo = 'x', obj = { };
obj[foo] = 'bar';
```

This creates a property named "x" rather than "foo". Whereas if we performed assignment via **dot notation**:

```
obj.foo = 'bar';
```

it would create a property named "foo".

So this is, arguably, Javascript limitation, since we can't have both object literals AND dynamically-evaluated properties:

```
obj.foo         // does NOT evaluate
obj[foo]        // evaluates

({ foo: ... })  // does NOT evaluate
?               // evaluates
```

**So why did I mention ECMAScript 5 before?**

Because in ECMAScript 6 (an upcoming standard), we're likely to have so-called ["computed property names"](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initialiser), where you'll be able to dynamically evaluate property name in an object literal like so:

```
var foo = 'x';
var obj = { [foo]: 'bar' };

obj.foo; // undefined
obj.x; // 'bar'
```

I'm really looking forward to this one.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. I'll rewrite the function. :)

Comment: BTW Thank you for the great work you have done with Fabric.js Its really amazing and makes life easier. Thank you

Comment: *“The only difference is that using identifier notation, you can only represent properties that are also valid... identifiers”* - Not just identifiers. Reserved words are also valid, .e.g `var o = { var: 123 };`